# ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль

Tags: python, pyqt5, cx-freeze

Написал простенькую программу на python использую библиотеку PyQt5. Скомпилировал ее в exe через компилятор cx_freeze скриптом setup.py. Все работает, но при запуске на другом компьютере, где нет python, в консоли выдает следующую ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__star
tup__.py", line 40, in run
File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Consol
e.py", line 23, in run
File "Fin_Filter.pyw", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

Мне нужно, чтобы программа запускалась на любой машине, где нет python
Писал на python 3.7, компилировал на системе Windows 10 x64.
Не запускается на системе Windows 8.1 x64. **Обновлено**: на Windows 10 x64 без ЯП тоже не работает.

setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 

setup(name = "Filter" , 
      version = "0.1" , 
      description = "" , 
      executables = [Executable("Fin_Filter.pyw")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить параметр include_msvcr, чтобы cx_Freeze добавил файлы Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_msvcr': True,
    }
}

setup(name = "Filter" , 
      version = "0.1" , 
      description = "" ,
      options=options,
      executables = [Executable("Fin_Filter.pyw")])
```

Comment: 1. cx_freeze не добавил файлы, пришлось качать в ручную.
2. Вылезла таже ошибка.